# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports, maven-assembly-plugin

My application generates PDF files using JasperReports. I generate one jar for my application using the Assembly Maven plugin.

The problem is that when I run the jar using the command line `java -cp "PrintOutCore-1.0.jar" com.soprabanking.printout.Launcher`, i get the following exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font: 
pdfFontName: DejaVu Sans
pdfEncoding: Identity-H
isPdfEmbedded : true
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getFont(JRPdfExporter.java:2176)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getChunk(JRPdfExporter.java:1967)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getPhrase(JRPdfExporter.java:1936)
    ...
```

But when I add the jasperreports-fonts jar to the classpath using the command line `java -cp "jasperreports-fonts-4.0.0.jar;PrintOutCore-1.0.jar" com.soprabanking.printout.Launcher`, the problem disappear and everything is ok.

How to run the jar correctly without adding the jasperreports-fonts jar to the classpath manually in the command line?

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.soprabanking</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <artifactId>PrintOutCore</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.soprabanking</groupId>
            <artifactId>PrintOutDao</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- BEGIN Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xmlunit/xmlunit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- FINISH Junit -->
        <!-- START jasper dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END jasper dependencies -->
        <!-- Begin Apache POI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- FINISH Apache POI -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.contentobjects.jnotify/jnotify -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.contentobjects.jnotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnotify</artifactId>
            <version>0.94</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Includes the runtime dependencies -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Accountancy*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*AccountOfficer*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*AccountsWithout*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*AutomaticRev*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*GeneralSummary*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*GrandLivre*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*RevaluationOn*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*SyntheticGeneral*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*SyntheticBalance*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*BceaoBalance*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*DailyReport*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*DailyTransaction*.java</include>
                        <include>com.soprabanking.printout.test.utils.*.java</include>
                        <include>com.soprabanking.printout.service.reportcreators.xls.XLSUtilsTest.java</include>
                        <include>com.soprabanking.printout.test.service.ParserXmlUtilsTest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Assembly plugin is missing something at packaging time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388856/maven-assembly-plugin-is-missing-something-at-packaging-time)

Comment: It is a bad practice to repost the question

Comment: I miss explained the old question, and i had no correct response.

Answer (score 1):

After a long time of searching, I found the root of the problem.

In fact, at packaging time the assembly plugin find the file **jasperreports_extension.properties** twice, so it deletes one and keep the other.

A solution is to replace the **Maven-Assembly-plugin** with the **Maven-Shade-plugin** and add a transformer to it.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                      <resource>jasperreports_extension.properties</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>junit:junit</artifact>
                        <includes>
                            <include>junit/framework/**</include>
                            <include>org/junit/**</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>org/junit/experimental/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>org/junit/runners/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```